# c++ constructor and initializer behavior. What's the difference between these 5 codes?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initializer

I'm new to c++ programming language. I wrote several patterns of code to understand c++ constructor and initializer. But I couldn't find out why one build fail and another doesn't. From my view, there seems no such difference that one fail and another doesn't. The code is the following 5 codes. What's the difference between code example 1-2, 2-3, 3-4, 4-5. Why one fail but another doesn't?

`Additional Info:`
I'm building these code with Xcode 8.2.

---

**The Code**

Example 1:

```
class A{
public:
  A(int xxx) { }
};

int main(){
  A a; // Fail here. I see this is because there is no default constructor in definition of class A.
}
```

Example 2:

```
class A{
public:
  A(int xxx) { }
};

class B{
public:
  A a; // No fail. Why? I supposed it will fail like Example 1.
};

int main(){

}
```

Example 3:

```
class A{
public:
  A(int xxx) { }
};

class B{
public:
  A a;           // No fail here.
  B(int xxx) { } // But fail here. Why? I just added constructor to Example 2.
};

int main(){

}
```

Example 4:

```
class A{
public:
  A(int xxx) { }
};

class B{
public:
  A a;
  B(int xxx) : a(123) { } // No fail. Why Just adding ":a(123)" works.
};

int main(){

}
```

Example 5:

```
class A{
public:
  A(int xxx) { }
};

class B{
public:
  A a;
  B(int xxx){ a = 123; } // Fail again. Why? I think ":a(123)" and "a=123" is same meaning.
};

int main(){

}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no error for example 2 since you never try to construct a `B`.  If you add to main `B b;` then you will get an error like

> error: use of deleted function 'B::B()'

The reason you do not get an error before you try to instantiate a `B` is because `A a;` is just a member declaration.  It is not until the constructor is called and you try to instantiate `a` that you find out it is not default constructable.

Example 3 is basically the same thing.  Now that you are defining a constructor the compiler will automatically add the default initialization of `a` to it since you did not provide one in the member initializer list.  When it does that it sees `A` is not default constructable so it issues the error.

Example 4 does not fail because you specify how to construct `a`.  Since you did that the compiler will not try to default construct it and instead it constructs `a` with the value you provided.

Example 5 fails again because of the same reason in example 3.  It tries to add a default initialization to the member initialization list but can't since it does not exists, which give you the error.

Comment: I think this is very detail and precise description of what's happening inside of these Examples. Thank you.

Comment: @KeiMinagawa No problem.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be getting the hang of most of this, so let me go through them all and clarify.

Example 1: You're trying to create an instance of A without supplying the constructor arguments it needs.

Example 2: The class `B` can't be instantiated since it needs to create an instance of `A` and you haven't specified which arguments to send to its constructor. You would get a compiler error here if you were to create an instance of `B` somewhere. For example by putting `B b;` in main().

Example 3: The constructor `B::B(int)` fails to compile because you haven't specified valid arguments to the constructor of `B::a` (its instance of `A`). You're getting the error here, since it's during this constructor you would have to specify the arguments to a``.

Example 4: Here you are specifying, in the initialization list of `B::B` which arguments it should pass to `B::a`. This is what you need to do in order for it to compile.

Example 5: Here you're trying to assign a the value of `123`. This is done in the body of the constructor `B::B`, which is called after all members of `B` have been initialized. It's not specifying the arguments to the constructor of `a`. It's just trying to assign a new value to it after it has already been constructed. Since you're not specifying a value which should be sent to the constructor of `a`, you get the same error as in Example 3.

Comment: This helped a lot. I read your answer and @NathanOliver's repeatedly. Finally I got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

- 1 vs 2: Example 2 don't fail because you never instantiate `B` o `A` in your main
- 2 vs 3: Example 3 fail because in you constructor of `B` you don't call to `A::A()` and `A` has no default constructor
- 3 vs 4: Example 4 don't fail because you call to `A::A()` in your `B` constructor.
- 4 vs 5: Example 5 fail because (again)you don't call to `A::A()` and `A` has no default constructor. But `123` can be asigned to `A` (because the **implicitly-declared copy assignment operator** is declared, and you have a constructor to build an `A` from an `int`)

Comment: Very simple, I like this. I came back this answer again and again when I was confused. Thank you.

Comment: I forgot to say that I think maybe `a=123` you last mentioned can create instance of A without a cast.

Comment: @KeiMinagawa you are totally right, in this case is ok, because the implicitly-declared copy assignment operator is declared, and you have a constructor to build an `A` from an `int`. Edited my answer.